# "I have stayed" or "I had been stayed"?

Tags: grammar, present-perfect

Which of these sentences are correct?

> I have stayed in your prestigious hotel from 11th-may-2015 to 18th may 2015.
>
> I had been stayed in your prestigious hotel from 11th-may-2015 to 18th may 2015.

Comment: You will get much better answers if you explain what about the sentences are confusing you.

Comment: I am confused in these sentences as i want to write in a grammatically correct manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Which of these sentences are correct?
>
> ```
> I have stayed in your prestigious hotel from 11th-may-2015 to 18th may 2015.
>
> I had been stayed in your prestigious hotel from 11th-may-2015 to 18th may 2015.
> ```

The correct sentence is :

*I stayed in your prestigious hotel from May 11(th) to May 18(th) 2015.*

Comment: as this is a past thing i stayed during 11 may to 18 may,Why i cannot use I had been staying

Comment: because the action of 'staying' is finished, in the other question you are still working with XY, that is the difference

Comment: In AmEnglish you can also say from 5/11 to 5/18 2015

Comment: I am clear with other question,credit goes to u .In this question As the action of staying is finished but it continued for a specific period of time ,"had" denotes past, "been" means it was continuous,"stayed'' denotes past. Honestly i am unable to understand the logic

Comment: you can use 'been' only if a gerund 'staying' follows, since the action is over there can be no gerund, that's the logic

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24060/discussion-between-user122708-and-mark).